# Change json string of form Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working with converting form data to json data. Here is my code:

```
  $.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';

        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {

        $('#result').append(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));

        return false;
    });
});
```

the above code gives the following json string:

```
  {"TypeName":["type1","type2"],"rate":["23","24"],"no:ofTickets":["23","24"],"allowedMembers": ["member1","member2"]}
```

But my need is to get json like this:

```
   {[
    {"TypeName":"type1","rate":"23","no:ofTickets":"23","allowedMembers":"member1"},
    {"TypeName":"type2","rate":"34","no:ofTickets":"56","allowedMembers":"member2"}
]}
```

how can i solve my problem??

Thanks

Comment: this data you are getting from server side ?

Comment: @Gaurav No actually this data is a FORM data from the clientSide

Answer (score 1):

[serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) already does exactly that, you just need to convert the data into your required format:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
  var o = {};
  var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function()
   {
     if (o[this.name] !== undefined)
     {
        if (!o[this.name].push) 
        {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    }
    else 
    {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
 });
 return o;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var elements = []; // Define an empty array
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();

    $.each(a, function() {
       ...

       elements.push(o); // Store your objects into the array
    });

    return elements; // return the array
}
```

Working example http://fiddle.jshell.net/f8Zkr/

Answer (score 0):

Change your searialzieObject function to :-

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
    var o = [];
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        var new_dict = {};   
        if (new_dict[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!new_dict[this.name].push) {
                new_dict[this.name] = [new_dict[this.name]];
            }
                new_dict[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            new_dict[this.name] = this.value || '';

        }
        o.push(new_dict);
    });
    return o;
};
```